# git push heroku masterでherokuにデプロイできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Gemfileです。

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.5.3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry-rails' 
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
end



group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
gem 'active_hash'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'mini_racer'
```

Gemfile.lockです。

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.3.7)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.7)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.3.7)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.7)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.7)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.7)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.3.7)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.7)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.7)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.7)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.3.7)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.3.7)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.7)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.7)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    active_hash (3.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    activejob (6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
    activerecord (6.0.3.7)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
    activestorage (6.0.3.7)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.7)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.7)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.7)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
    activesupport (6.0.3.7)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.8)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.8.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    factory_bot (6.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    factory_bot_rails (6.1.0)
      factory_bot (~> 6.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.0.0)
    faker (2.17.0)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
    ffi (1.15.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.12.1)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.17, < 3)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    libv8-node (15.14.0.1)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.9.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.1)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_magick (4.11.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.5.1)
    mini_racer (0.4.0)
      libv8-node (~> 15.14.0.0)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    mysql2 (0.5.3)
    nio4r (2.5.7)
    nokogiri (1.11.3)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    parallel (1.20.1)
    parser (3.0.1.1)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
    pry (0.14.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    pry-rails (0.3.9)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (3.12.6)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.3.7)
      actioncable (= 6.0.3.7)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.3.7)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.3.7)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.7)
      actiontext (= 6.0.3.7)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.7)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.7)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.7)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.7)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.3.7)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.3.7)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.7)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.7)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rainbow (3.0.0)
    rake (13.0.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.4)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.1.1)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rspec-core (3.10.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.10.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.10.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-rails (4.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      railties (>= 4.2)
      rspec-core (~> 3.10)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.10)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.10)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10)
    rspec-support (3.10.2)
    rubocop (1.14.0)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.0.0.0)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.5.0, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.5.0)
      parser (>= 3.0.1.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.11.0)
    ruby-vips (2.1.0)
      ffi (~> 1.12)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.1.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.9)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    unicode-display_width (2.0.0)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_hash
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.2)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  devise
  factory_bot_rails
  faker
  image_processing (~> 1.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mini_magick
  mini_racer
  mysql2 (= 0.5.3)
  pry-rails
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 6.0.0)
  rspec-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  rubocop
  sass-rails (~> 5)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 4.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.5p114

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

heroku logs --tail --app実行結果です。

```
2021-05-06T09:19:09.501879+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate` by user メールアドレス
2021-05-06T09:19:10.269368+00:00 heroku[run.2155]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-06T09:19:10.803157+00:00 heroku[run.2155]: Awaiting client
2021-05-06T09:19:12.453814+00:00 heroku[run.2155]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2021-05-06T09:19:17.701679+00:00 heroku[run.2155]: Process exited with status 127
2021-05-06T09:19:17.914072+00:00 heroku[run.2155]: State changed from up to complete
2021-05-06T09:19:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-05-06T09:19:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/f8a5ac35-99b5-42f1-8f75-98f7a258e760/activity/builds/0e604b70-5f55-45f0-a4d5-f6f0824bcd75
2021-05-06T09:45:01.427080+00:00 app[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by user メールアドレス
2021-05-06T09:45:01.427080+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user メールアドレス
2021-05-06T09:46:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-05-06T09:46:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/f8a5ac35-99b5-42f1-8f75-98f7a258e760/activity/builds/f91048c3-0fd4-4794-9c3d-1822f912dc87
2021-05-06T10:19:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-05-06T10:19:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/f8a5ac35-99b5-42f1-8f75-98f7a258e760/activity/builds/3acd51aa-38ac-43d9-904c-7f182550d09a
```

git push heroku master 実行結果です

```
Enumerating objects: 631, done.
Counting objects: 100% (631/631), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (597/597), done.
Writing objects: 100% (631/631), 9.69 MiB | 2.47 MiB/s, done.
Total 631 (delta 308), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:                         Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.16
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.5
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.16
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-20"] but your local platform
remote:        is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock
remote:        --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
remote:        Bundler Output: Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-20"] but your local platform
remote:        is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock
remote:        --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 8ec4daa2b239133614e9458a901765d37cb4549c
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 8ec4daa2b239133614e9458a901765d37cb4549c
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to アプリ名.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/アプリ名.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/アプリ名.git'
```

Rubyをインストールしたがバージョンが変わらないとのことなのでvim ~/.zshrcのインサートモードで
export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"を追加しました。
その結果ruby -vをしたらrailsのバージョンが無事切り替わってました。
でもエラーがまだ変わりませんでした。

```
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin20]
```

もう一週間以上解決できずにいます、どなたかお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
```

こちらの2行に説明があります。`sqlite3`はHerokuではサポートされていないとのことです。
`Gemfile`にある`sqlite3`の行を`development`グループに入れれば解決すると思われます。

Herokuの詳細な利用方法については[こちら](https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/getting-started-with-rails6)を参照してください。

Comment: sqlite3をdevelopmentグループに入れたんですがデプロイできませんでした。

Comment: エラー文にあるbundle lock　--add-platform x86_64-linuxを実行したんですがうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: `bundle lock　--add-platform x86_64-linux`を実行すると、`Gemfile.lock`にある
`
PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-20
`
の行に`x86_64-linux`が追加されるはずです。まずはそれを確認してみてください。

Comment: PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-20
  x86_64-linux　確認できました。

Comment: やはり本番環境ではPostgresqlを用いるようにしないといけないのでしょうか？前回アプリをherokuに公開したときはPostgresqlは使わなかったはずなのですが

Comment: ちなみに今乗っているGemfileとかは最初から一度アプリを作り直したものを乗せています

Comment: 質問の途中でアプリを変更してしまうと、それまでの積み重ねが無意味になってしまうのでやめたほうがいいと思います。

Comment: ごめんなさい。ではやはりPostgresqlを導入すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: データーベースがmysql2', '0.5.3'なんですが新たにsqlite3をインストールする必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答を編集し、リンクを追加しましたのでそちらをご確認ください。アプリを作り直しているということで、このコメント欄で私が書いたアドバイスをもう一度実行し直す必要もあるでしょう。

Comment: Heroku スターターガイドではsqlite3を使ってて自分はmaysqlを使ってるんですがその場合は新たにsqlite3に変更した方が良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 「スターターガイドではsqlite3を使ってて」とありますが、何を読んでそう思いましたか？

Comment: スターターガイドのどのあたりにsqlite3を使うと書いてあったでしょうか。

Comment: pg gemの追加のところです。

Comment: `--database=postgresql​ を指定せずに作成された既存のアプリを使用している場合は、Rails プロジェクトに pg​ gem を追加する必要があります。Gemfile​ を編集し、以下の行を変更します。
gem 'sqlite3'
変更後は次のようになります。
gem 'pg'
開発には PostgreSQL を使用することを強くお勧めします。処理中の開発と​開発環境を一致させることで、環境の違いによる微妙なバグの発生が阻止されます。Postgres はローカルにインストールしてください​ (まだシステムにない場合)。`とありますから、PostgreSQLを利用すべきということになると思います。

Comment: gem 'sqlite3'がそもそもないんですがこれはそのままgem 'pg'を追加すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そのまま`pg`を追加し、以後はスターターガイドの指示に従ってください。

Comment: gem install pgをターミナルで実行してpgをインストールした場合Gemfileにgem 'pg' と追加で記入するんでしょうか？

Comment: ドキュメントに従ってください。エラーが出たらまた質問してください。

Comment: 無事解決できました。

Comment: おめでとうございます！どのように解決できたのか書いていただけると、他の人の助けになると思うのでぜひお願いします。